# Проблема при скролинге страницы вниз

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $("#scroll-down").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#portfolio-scroll').position().top
      },1000);      
    });
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}

.wrepper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-zona h1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-zona h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.main-zona {
  position: relative;
}

.main-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main-icon-down {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-icon-down:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*Portfolio*/

.portfolio {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
}

.portfolio-block img {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 29px 0px rgba(87, 92, 97, 0.54);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
}

.portfolio a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 20px auto 50px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test - Portfolio</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello-embedded.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/main-bg.jpg">
    <div class="main-overlay"></div>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index-en.html">
      <div class="en-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index.html">
      <div class="ru-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index-pl.html">
      <div class="pl-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="wrepper">
      <div class="main-zona">
        <h1>Test Test Test</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h2>Test Test TestTest Test TestTest <br>Test TestTest Test Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="main-icon-down" id="scroll-down" href="#portfolio-scroll"><i class="icon-down"></i></a>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio-scroll">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="container-header">Portfolio</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Work №1">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Work №2">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Work №3">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/parallax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scroll-down.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, которая приводит в действие скролинг вниз (`.main-icon-down`), по странице на долю секунды мигает и появляется блок (`.portfolio`) к которому идет прокрутка, после чего он исчезает, а потом уже страничка плавно прокручивается вниз.

Помогите избавится от мигания при нажатия на кнопку. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Припишите return false так якорь срабатывать не будет и мельканий тоже не будет.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $("#scroll-down").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#portfolio-scroll').position().top
      },1000); 
      return false;
    });
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}

.wrepper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-zona h1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-zona h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.main-zona {
  position: relative;
}

.main-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main-icon-down {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-icon-down:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*Portfolio*/

.portfolio {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
}

.portfolio-block img {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 29px 0px rgba(87, 92, 97, 0.54);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
}

.portfolio a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 20px auto 50px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test - Portfolio</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello-embedded.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/main-bg.jpg">
    <div class="main-overlay"></div>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index-en.html">
      <div class="en-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index.html">
      <div class="ru-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index-pl.html">
      <div class="pl-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="wrepper">
      <div class="main-zona">
        <h1>Test Test Test</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h2>Test Test TestTest Test TestTest <br>Test TestTest Test Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="main-icon-down" id="scroll-down" href="#portfolio-scroll"><i class="icon-down"></i></a>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio-scroll">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="container-header">Portfolio</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Work №1">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Work №2">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Work №3">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/parallax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scroll-down.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на кнопку происходит переход по якорю, а потом только обработка действий js.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $("#scroll-down").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#portfolio-scroll').position().top
      },1000);      
    });
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}

.wrepper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-zona h1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-zona h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.main-zona {
  position: relative;
}

.main-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main-icon-down {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-icon-down:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*Portfolio*/

.portfolio {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
}

.portfolio-block img {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 29px 0px rgba(87, 92, 97, 0.54);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
}

.portfolio a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 20px auto 50px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test - Portfolio</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello-embedded.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/main-bg.jpg">
    <div class="main-overlay"></div>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index-en.html">
      <div class="en-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index.html">
      <div class="ru-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://andrii1202.github.io/index-pl.html">
      <div class="pl-icon position"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="wrepper">
      <div class="main-zona">
        <h1>Test Test Test</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h2>Test Test TestTest Test TestTest <br>Test TestTest Test Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="main-icon-down" id="scroll-down" href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-down"></i></a>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio-scroll">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="container-header">Portfolio</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Work №1">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Work №2">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Work №3">
            <a href="#">See the sample</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/parallax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scroll-down.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно заблокировать переход по якорю.

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#scroll-down").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#portfolio-scroll').position().top
      },1000);
      return false;
    });
};
```